# Existing ValidateForm in excel checking on double entries

Tags: excel

I'm just starting with VBA and found an existing User form that I could use, but I like to insert a part that is checking based on data that will be filled in if this data doesn't already exist in the sheet where the data is stored. Could anyone help me with this?

I have tried several things but till now no success, so hopefully someone could support this.

here is a part of my code, I like to have to check before saving the data of course.

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim iRow As Long
    
    iRow = Sheets("Data").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    If ValidateForm = True Then
    
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
        
           .Range("A" & iRow).Value = iRow - 1
           .Range("B" & iRow).Value = cmbWarehouse.Text
           .Range("C" & iRow).Value = CmbMachine.Text
           .Range("D" & iRow).Value = txtMachinenr.Text
           .Range("E" & iRow).Value = TxtUrenstand.Text
           .Range("F" & iRow).Value = DTPicker1.Value
           
           
        End With
        Call Reset
    Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thnx

Comment: You can use `Range.Find` here probably.

Comment: were I need to insert this part of Range.Find, I prefer based on two collums Range "E" and Range "F"